# Learning Python - What cases does my code get wrong?

Tags: python

I'm learning python.  Below are two functions that accomplish the same thing with two different approaches.  One I came up with on my own, the other was given by code academy.

My question is, for the experienced programmers, which one would you use and why?  Are you indifferent to either one? What cases does my code get wrong?

***********#1****************

```
def censor(text, word):
  stars = ""
  for x in word:
    stars = stars + "*"

  text = text.replace(word, stars)
  return text
```

***********#2****************

```
def censor(text, word):
  words = text.split()
  print words
  result = ''
  stars = '*' * len(word)
  count = 0
  for i in words:
      if i == word:
          words[count] = stars
      count += 1
  result =' '.join(words)

  return result
```

Comment: Opinion based...

Comment: Perhaps a more productive question would be "What cases does my code get wrong?", although even that is close to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DavisHerring I wouldn't say such a question would belong at Code Review. This questions seems to be more of "What's the difference between code A and code B?" Code Review is for "How can code A be better?" (preferably no code B included)

Comment: @SimonForsberg & Davis On top of that: the 2nd piece of code wasn't written by the OP. On Code Review, one is supposed to know why you wrote the code you posted and be at least the maintainer of said code.

Comment: @Mast: Of course #2 wasn't written by the OP; it's just the motivation for asking "Is #1 any good (given that #2, from a reliable source, is so different)?".

Comment: @DavisHerring - I'm not opposed to moving it there.  For those of us new to the site, it's not intuitive where to post.  1) I didn't know of such a section and 2) wouldn't know how to put it there.  I simply clicked "Ask Question" and posted.

Comment: @JasonLackey: If you rephrase it along my suggested lines, I'll be glad to answer it right here.

Comment: @DavisHerring - Well I appreciate it, but that's not what I want to know.  I mis-typed the original post and have corrected it.   What I really want is insight from experienced people and to be honest, I find stackoverflow to not be very helpful.  Instead of mentoring/guiding me, I get a bunch of down votes and now I've been blocked from posting...  It is what it is, but what itsn't not is intuitive.

Comment: @JasonLackey: My “insight” is that the version you wrote commits the [clbuttic mistake](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem), along with using a [Schlemiel the Painter](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm) algorithm (which Python may or may not optimize away out of the goodness of its heart).  I therefore did not vote to close as opinion-based, because it’s more reasonable to call #1 buggy (which puts it back in Stack Overflow’s arena).

Comment: @DavisHerring: O.k.  THAT is good advice. Very good. I can put that in my pocket and use it later. Thank you.

Comment: @JasonLackey: Perhaps now you understand why I proposed the "more productive question".  You can still edit it; it might even buy you an upvote.

Comment: `1` Of course it's confusing which [se] site to post to, so you have [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598), [ask] and [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). `2` You ask a off-topic question on a site and complains the site for being unhelpful, it's your fault. `3` [Downvotes are meant to indicate that the content is bad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269461).

Comment: @user202729 - I'd argue this point with you but it won't accomplish anything, therefore... I won't.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with #1 because using inbuilt functions like `.replace() and .split()`would be more efficient than writing your own replace code.

```
def censor(text, word):
  stars = ""
  for x in word:
    stars = stars + "*"

  text = text.replace(word, stars)
  return text
```

This is better.

Answer (score 0):

1st function has no result defined, so it will produce an error.
2nd function produces some result..

```
a = 'cat'
b = 'meow'
c = censor(a, b)
```

produces

```
['cat']
cat
```

Comment: Code has been edited, 1st function was supposed to return `text`